# How to get data to off-chain worker from runtime?

Tags: rust, runtime, offchain-worker

Is any option to get data to off-chain workers from runtime?
For example, I have used runtime to store something.
How can I access this data from off-chain woker without using HTTP calls?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean accessing the pallet's storage? Yes, off-chain workers can do this. Take a look e.g. [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ce10b9f29353e89fc3e59d447041bb29622def3f/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs#L196) – `average_price` is reading data from the `Prices` storage.

Comment: From this readme: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/ce10b9f29353e89fc3e59d447041bb29622def3f/frame/examples/offchain-worker
we know that we can send data from off-chain worker -- > runtime. What if would like to send the data from runtime to an off-chain worker?